# filtering data from Pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

**Background:** I am trying to use data from a csv file to make asks questions and make conclusions base on data. The data is a log of patient visits from a clinic in Brazil, including additional patient data, and whether the patient was a no show or not. I have chosen to examine correlations between the patient's age and the no show data.

**Problem:** Given visit number, patient ID, age, and no show data, how do I compile an array of ages that correlate with the each unique patient ID (so that I can evaluate the mean age of total unique patients visiting the clinic).

**My code:**

```
# data set of no shows at a clinic in Brazil
noshow_data = pd.read_csv('noshowappointments-kagglev2-may-2016.csv')

noshow_df = pd.DataFrame(noshow_data)
```

Here is the beginning of the code, with the head of the whole dataframe of the csv given

[image]

```
# Next I construct a dataframe with only the data I'm interested in:

ptid = noshow_df['PatientId']
ages = noshow_df['Age']
noshow = noshow_df['No-show']
ptid_ages_noshow = pd.DataFrame({'PatientId' : pt_id, 'Ages' : ages, 
                                 'No_show' : noshow})

ptid_ages_noshow
```

Here I have sorted the data to show the multiple visits of a unique patient

[image]

```
# Now, I know how to determine the total number of unique patients:

# total number of unique patients
num_unique_pts = noshow_df.PatientId.unique()
len(num_unique_pts)
```

If I want to find the mean age of all the patients during the course of all visits I would use:

```
# mean age of all vists
ages = noshow_data['Age']
ages.mean()
```

So my question is this, how could I find the mean age of all the unique patients?

Comment: Can you please provide your data or example data in copy-pastable form so we can reproduce? See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) function available in `pandas` with restriction to the concerned columns :

```
ptid_ages_noshow[['PatientId','Ages']].groupby('PatientId').mean()
```

Answer (score 0):

So you only want to keep one appointment per patient for the calculation? This is how to do it:

```
noshow_df.drop_duplicates('PatientId')['Age'].mean()
```

Keep in mind that the age of people changes over time. You need to decide how you want to handle this.